# How to add identity seed on the ID in the latest EF 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Please do not mark this question as a duplicated one, as I have checked the similar question and their error messages and versions are NOT same.
Many of them used the older version which could be 3 years ago, so I would think that for the latest version of EF which is what I am using, there should be a different way to achieve what I want. Thank you.**

I am trying to create a table, Event, with the latest version of EF 6.1.3(I'm using the code first way).

Everything goes right, only the Identity Seed doesn't work for the ID property on Event table.

Here is my code:

```
  public class Event
    {
        public Event()
        {
            Organizers = new HashSet<AspNetUser>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        ....................

        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> Hosts {get; set;}
     }
```

And in the AspNetUser class I added these lines of code:

```
public class AspNetUser
{
     ................

     public AspNetUser()
            base:("theConnectionString")
     {
          Events = new HashSet<Event>();
     }

            public virtual ICollection<Event> Events {get; set;}

     ................
}
```

And I updated the OnModelCreating() method in my db context class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUsers)
            .WithMany(e => e.AspNetRoles)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("UserId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserClaims)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserLogins)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Organizers)
            .WithMany(e => e.Events)
            .Map(e => e.ToTable("AspNetUsers").MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("EventId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

As you can see that the last 2 blocks are my code.

Then I ran :

> Add-Migration AddEventTable
>
> Update-Database

The generated 201504071252445_AddEventTable.cs looks like this:

```
public partial class AddEventTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.AspNetUsers", newName: "AspNetUsers1");
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Events",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                        Venue = c.String(),
                        StartDateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        EndDateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        Capacity = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Content = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        EventId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.EventId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Events", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers1", t => t.EventId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.EventId);
            
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "EventId", "dbo.AspNetUsers1");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserId", "dbo.Events");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", new[] { "EventId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropTable("dbo.Events");
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.AspNetUsers1", newName: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
```

As you can see that, it adds an unwanted line of code in the Up():

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.AspNetUsers", newName: "AspNetUsers1");
```

and in the Down()

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.AspNetUsers1", newName: "AspNetUsers");
```

And I have tried to insert value into this table without providing value for ID, but it failed:

Here is the sql query

```
insert into Events values( 'Title', 'Address', '2015-04-09 20:00:00.000','2015-04-09 20:00:00.000', 30, 'Content!')
```

Here is the error message.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
> definition.

So my question is:

1. How to add an identity seed on my Event ID.
2. Why does the generated code rename my AspNetUser table to AspNetUser1?

Thank you.

Comment: Just because questions are older does not mean they are no longer relevant.  In fact, EF has not changed in any way that would be relevant to your question since at least version 4.1.  So any question that solves your problem in an older version would solve your problem in the most recent version.

Comment: hi @ErikFunkenbusch that's fine. I have tried those solutions, but none of them work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is this, specifically the `Map()` call:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Organizers)
            .WithMany(e => e.Events)
            .Map(e => e.ToTable("AspNetUsers").MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("EventId"));
```

You're mapping the connector between your Event class and your AspNetUsers class to the table "AspNetUsers". This is what is causing the code to rename your existing table to something else. You've also got the mapping backwards. `MapLeftKey` would refer to the `Event` table. `MapRightKey` would refer to the `AspNetUsers` table. I would change that to be something like (unnecessarily verbose, I'm aware, just for illustrative purposes)

```
.Map(e => e.ToTable("AspNetUsersToEventsMapping")
           .MapLeftKey("EventId")
           .MapRightKey("UserId"))
```

The second part of your problem is that your `Id` field is a `string`. I don't believe string fields can be `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` - it should be a numeric value.

Comment: Perfect~!!!! the type of my ID is where I made a mistake! Now it work! One more thing to mention: I commented out the last 2 blocks in the OnModelCreating() method which are written mannully by myself and it still works. So I am confused about whether do I need these 2 blocks(I mean the modelBuilder.Entity().....) or not?

Comment: @Franva - Well, you don't need the last one for sure, because you are also using the Attribute (which does the same thing).  Can't tell about the other one because you haven't included the definitions of that set of entities

Comment: hi Erik, please see my update. Also, I think the annotation [Key] is not necessary as the property is named as ID and EF will treat it as the ID by default, Am I correct?